# EnversHibernateToolTask in NetBean build file issue

Tags: netbeans, ant, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to incorporate hibernate schema generator for Envers.
I've add this target:

```
    <target name="schemaexport"
        description="Exports a generated schema to DB and file">
    <path id="hibernate.classpath">
        <pathelement path="./lib/hibernate-persistence/*.jar" />
    </path>
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool"
             classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask"
             classpathref="hibernate.classpath"/>

    <hibernatetool destdir=".">
        <classpath>
            <fileset refid="lib.hibernate" />
            <path location="${build.demo.dir}" />
            <path location="${build.main.dir}" />
        </classpath>
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="AuroraServicePU" />
        <hbm2ddl
          drop="false"
          create="true"
          export="false"
          outputfilename="versioning-ddl.sql"
          delimiter=";"
          format="true"/>
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

The problem is that I get the error 
**taskdef class org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[myproject\lib\hibernate-persistence*.jar]**

Help will be great.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your path is incorrect. I don't believe you can use wildcards in a `pathelement`.

Try changing your `path` to be:

```
<path id="hibernate.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

If that fails, run ant with the `-v` tag and check the debug for more hints.